# A symmetric function related to sums of square roots

Tags: co.combinatorics, symmetric-functions

Let $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$ be indeterminates (say over $\mathbb{Q}$). For
every sequence $\epsilon=(\epsilon_1, \dots,\epsilon_n)\in\{-1,1\}^n$
define $$ y_\epsilon = \sum_i \epsilon_i \sqrt{x_i}. $$ Let $f_{n,k}$
denote the $k$th elementary symmetric function of all the
$y_\epsilon$'s. Thus $f_{n,2j+1}=0$ and $f_{n,2j}$ is a symmetric
function of degree $j$ in the $x_i$'s. What can be said about this
symmetric function? For instance, $f_{n,2}=-2^{n-1}(x_1+\cdots+x_n)$
and $f_{4,4}=12h_1^2+16h_2$, where $h_\lambda$ is a complete symmetric
function.

In particular, does $f_{n,k}$ have an interesting expansion in
terms of any of the ``classical'' bases for symmetric functions
(monomial, power sum, elementary, complete, forgotten, Schur)? Is
there some way to normalize $f_{n,k}$ so that it makes sense to let
$n\to \infty$?

Comment: Is there possibly a connection (e.g., simple change of variables) to the "Boolean product polynomials" studied by Billey, Rhoades, and Tewari in: https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.11165 ?

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/q/123058

Comment: This [online Sage code](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJylkctqwzAQRfcG_8NAKEhBxEVkVci264YsQ2qMHrVw9LAsQ03pv1eWldpddxZi7pWY4VztgFntxiAGcDVHEy4LLmTsrawnZAjHL2UBsZQE_kSzmMuLMHoDz4tzmTSc5lOL4BV7HQ0LypoBnc94eZHvDxplIw-g7wb2IBsWrFfNHXEc5TBqBPra36AC5y1H6z3dCwzSehCgDPRL38_9W-ODWrbyqqJEN5_1XZiP0J4Mhri1LHYrrqy_DOm-f5FlpO02tN2_aF2mdQ9akQ3xMNpstGseQ7QSOYsRJOzNPyROPnMGWEQgbJYOiWt3w39TbVEcl5CdVyagiHckNKWwMY7R-AH8-I5P&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) computes polynomials $f_{n,k}$ in terms of complete symmetric polynomials. At very least it confirms the values $f_{4,2}$ and $f_{4,4}$.

Comment: Also related: https://mathoverflow.net/q/302490

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/q/413703


where the $f_{n-1,k}$ (in the $x_{i}^{2}$ instead of the $x_i$) are the coefficients of the expansion of $Q$ as a polynomial in $x_n$.

Answer (score 4):

(Not an answer, just some thoughts I find useful.) There is a nice identity $$\sum_{(\varepsilon_1,\dots,\varepsilon_n)\in\{-1,1\}^n}\cos\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\varepsilon_iz_i\right)=2^n\prod_{i=1}^n\cos(z_i)$$ one can obtain by induction on $n$. More generally, if one defines $R_a=\{z\in\mathbb C:z^a=1\}$ and $$f_a(x)=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{x^{an}}{(an)!}=\frac1a\sum_{r\in R_a}\exp(rx),$$
then $$\sum_{(\varepsilon_1,\dots,\varepsilon_n)\in R_a^n} f_a\left(t\cdot\sum_{i=1}^n\varepsilon_iz_i\right)=a^n\prod_{i=1}^nf_a(t\cdot z_i).$$ Expanding both sides as formal power series in $t$, it follows that $$\frac1{m!}\sum_{(\varepsilon_1,\dots,\varepsilon_n)\in R_a^n} \left(\sum_{i=1}^n\varepsilon_iz_i\right)^m = a^n\sum_{(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n)\in P_m}\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{z_i^{\lambda_i}}{\lambda_i!},$$
where $P_m=\{(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n)\in(a\mathbb Z_{\ge0})^n:\sum\lambda_i=m\}$, which is obviously empty for $a\nmid m$. So, if $z_i=\sqrt[a]{x_i}$, one gets the expansion of $ak$-th power sum of all $y_\varepsilon$ in terms of monomial symmetric polynomials. Unfortunately, Newton formulas seem to produce such a mess, so some amount of combinatorial work is required to get the coefficients of the required expansions. I'll add it later

Comment: The formula you are using is essentially [series multisection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_multisection).

Comment: The same symmetric polynomial as in the rhs of your last formula (for $a=2$) appears in [my answer](https://mathoverflow.net/q/432318) to a related question.